# ChartJS re-rendering bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js2

So I'm building a trading tool and am using chartJS for the charts. This is how my charts look now on the page:

[image]

So my problem is that when I change the time period of the chart, the chart shows randomly the old data mixed with the new one.

You can see the behaviour here: https://gifyu.com/image/vda5

For now I can't use the Big chart together with the small one on the same page because the big chart which has the timing period has also multiple AJAX calls so every time I click on "1W" for example, a new call is being made and the chart is drawn over.

**Things I tried:**

I know that for dynamic charts in chartJS I have to destroy the chart, so I'm using

```
if (window.chart !== undefined)  window.chart.destroy();
```

and for the small charts I use an empty array and push the elements inside. Here is how I do it:

```
if ($(quoteDisplayEl).hasClass('quoteDisplay-light')) {
    chartHandel.push(quoteChart);
} else {
    window.chart = quoteChart;
}
```

so for the big chart I assign it to a global variable and the small one I push it to the empty array - that allows me to have multiple charts on one page.

But in order for the big chart to be destroyed I should destroy and re-render all charts from scratch (I guess) and I tried multiple was of achieving that with now luck.

Unfortunately the code is over 500 lines and has lots of variable data coming from APIs and DB thus I can't make a fiddle demo.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `chart.update()` over `chart.destroy()`.

[Here's a small, simple example how I usually update data.](https://jsbin.com/semizutico/1/edit?html,js,output)

1. I make one object per chart with labels (empty array) and data (empty array) and colors and all the stuff you need.
2. I fill these arrays with data I get (AJAX).
3. Optional: If I get all the data and need to filter it to show less data, I copy my object to keep all the data I got and have all the data I need now for my chart in another object
4. Make an `updateChart()` function which alters your displayed data or saved data from your backup object or use new data from a new AJAX request.
5. End your `updateChart()` with chart.update() (or whatever your chart is called).

Multiple charts shouldn't be a problem and you shouldn't have to destroy your chart.

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting, I thought none will look at that )) I tried update, but no luck. This is how I update the charts: https://prnt.sc/pzm3qy and here is where I add the charts as a global variable or add it inside an array: https://prnt.sc/pzm4gm  But I assume with your solution I can only use chartHandel.push for all charts, however, it doesn't work, the chart still re-renders..

Comment: I will take a look at it later. But the code would be very helpful. Would be great if you can post it somewhere, doesn't need to be working, I can filter out what I need. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure thing, I removed most of the code which was not in any way related to the issue, and left only the Ajax call and the chart data and graph. You can find it here: https://pastebin.com/p0Ar0X95  Thanks :)